# Is it possible to access an npm configuration in gulp

Tags: npm, gulp

I'm using browsersync in gulp, and the instance is hosted in IIS so we're using the `proxy` option of browsersync.

However, the proxy url might be different for different developers.

My idea is to access the npm configuration if the user has a different port than the default.  And allow the individual developers to specify what their URL is, if it's not defined gulp will use the default value that's hardcoded.

Is it possible for gulp to access npm config?  Or is there a better way to allow users to set local configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Can they pass in their url/port number as a flag to the browsersync task?

```
var util = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    var url = util.env.url;
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: url
    });
});
```

Then the command would be:
`gulp browser-sync --url http://example.com`

You could also checkin a `sample.config.js` file that users could rename (ex `config.js`) and the browsersync task could check for values in that file if it exists.

If it's just browser-sync they need to start and no other gulp tasks, users could start it from a batch file.

```
SET MY-PORT=8088
SET MY-URL="http://example.com:%MY-PORT%"
browser-sync start --proxy %MY-URL%%
```

Windows users can run those from the `run` prompt so browser-sync could be started with a keyboard shortcut.